# Enumerator: collect method with two parameters

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I have this code:

```
users = ["foo", "bar"]
users.collect { |item, value = []| value << {:name => item} }.flatten
```

That is working like the wind in ruby-1.9.2:

```
=> [{:name=>"foo"}, {:name=>"bar"}]
```

But this does not work in ruby-1.8.7 because it does not like collect getting two parameters:

```
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):2: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '|'
users.collect { |item, value = []| value << {:name => item} }.flatten
```

[Reading the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000247) that's true, collect does not expect two parameters, but it's working in ruby 1.9.2. So am I missing something, my `Array`/`Enumerable` is being patched in some weird way or is the documentation wrong?

Comment: In a map/collect you never make a in-place updated (a side-effect), that's the first principle of functional programming (which is where map comes from)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are missing something. This is what you want to do, and it works in both 1.9 and 1.8:

```
users.collect { |i| { :name => i } }
```

Comment: +1 `collect` already implicitly does the "append iteratively to an empty starting list" logic that you're trying to do yourself - that (a) is the reason it exists in the first place; (b) is why it has the name that it does: the results of each evaluation of the block are "collected".

Answer (score 2):

1.8.7 isn't complaining about the block getting two parameters, it is complaining about your attempt to provide a default value for the second parameter. This:

```
users.collect { |item, value| value << {:name => item} }.flatten
```

parses fine in 1.8.7 but, of course, it falls over at run time because `value` is `nil`.

1.9 does allow default values for block arguments (see below).

So no, the documentation isn't wrong, you're just using [`collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001490) in a strange way that works in 1.9.2 because it allows default values for block arguments.

Anyway, your using of `collect` is a bit convoluted and might not be doing quite what you think it is doing, you should listen to Casper and just do a simple `collect`:

```
users.collect { |item| { :name => item } }
```

But, if you have a thing for `<<` and want to use it no matter what, you could use [`inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494) in both 1.8.7 and 1.9.2:

```
users.inject([ ]) { |value, item| value << { :name => item } }
```

That is pointless complexity though.

---

You piqued my curiosity so I went to the Ruby parser files for an authoritative reference. Pointless busy work perhaps but "pointless" and "bad" are different things.

The 1.9.2-p180 `parse.y` has these things:

```
block_param     : f_arg ',' f_block_optarg ',' f_rest_arg opt_f_block_arg
                | f_arg ',' f_block_optarg ',' f_rest_arg ',' f_arg opt_f_block_arg
                | f_arg ',' f_block_optarg opt_f_block_arg
                /* ... */
f_block_optarg  : f_block_opt
f_block_opt     : tIDENTIFIER '=' primary_value
```

If you trace through it a bit, you'll see that the `block_param` rule is used for things like this:

```
{ |eggs| ... }
{ |two_cent, stamp| ... }
{ |where_is, pancakes = 'house'| ... }
```

and the `do`/`end` form as well. Then trace from `block_param` down to `f_block_opt` and you'll see where default values are explicitly allowed by the grammar.

OTOH, The 1.8.7-p248 `parse.y` has this:

```
opt_block_var : none
              | '|' /* none */ '|'
              | tOROP
              | '|' block_var '|'
```

There is nothing in `block_var` that allows default values for block arguments. The `tOROP` is just there to allow both of these forms:

```
{ | | pancakes }    # '|' /* none */ '|'
{ ||  pancakes }    # tOROP, the logical "or" operator: ||
```